# How to parse html to get 3 url's to seperate Strings?

Tags: java, android, dom, jsoup

I am trying to parse each URL from this HTML

```
<div class="latest-media-images">
    <div class="hdr-article">LATEST IMAGES</div>
    <a class="lnk-thumb" href="http://media.pc.ign.com/media/093/093395/imgs_1.html"><img id="thumbImg1" src="http://media.ignimgs.com/media/thumb/351/3513804/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-20110824023151748_thumb_ign.jpg" class="latestMediaThumb" alt="" height="109" width="145"></a>
    <a class="lnk-thumb" href="http://media.pc.ign.com/media/093/093395/imgs_1.html"><img id="thumbImg2" src="http://media.ignimgs.com/media/thumb/351/3513803/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-20110824023149685_thumb_ign.jpg" class="latestMediaThumb" alt="" height="109" width="145"></a>
    <a class="lnk-thumb" href="http://media.pc.ign.com/media/093/093395/imgs_1.html"><img id="thumbImg3" src="http://media.ignimgs.com/media/thumb/351/3513802/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-20110824023147685_thumb_ign.jpg" class="latestMediaThumb" alt="" height="109" width="145"></a>
</div>
```

I want to parse each URL to a seperate String using jsoup.

Ive been doing pretty good with jsoup parsing. But what i want to do here i dont know where to begin to get each url in its own String

How do i go about doing this here? Parsing and then getting it to seperate Strings?

EDIT:

Or if i cant get them to seperate strings, Maybe i could set them to a list? and load them by position some way?

OR Could i load each one...1 by 1?

Just some suggestions im thinking of...

EDIT: From the comment below i see that this is what i need to extract the links as a list.

```
/**
* Example program to list links from a URL.
*/
public class ListLinks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
        String url = args[0];
        print("Fetching %s...", url);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
        Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");

        print("\nMedia: (%d)", media.size());
        for (Element src : media) {
            if (src.tagName().equals("img"))
                print(" * %s: <%s> %sx%s (%s)",
                        src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"), src.attr("width"), src.attr("height"),
                        trim(src.attr("alt"), 20));
            else
                print(" * %s: <%s>", src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"));
        }
    }
}
```

I dont think this is exactly optimized for my use but in the right direction.

What do i need to do have it extract my example list above of html src's?

Comment: Hope this example url will help you out - http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

Comment: @AVD Check out my edit for your link.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want all images? Then try this [XPath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html#package_description) expression:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//img", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

List<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node img = nodes.item(i);
    imageUrls.add(img.getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue());
}
```